# JAX-WS - Remove inner XML root from VO parameter

Tags: java, xml, web-services, dom, jax-ws

i am having a problem with annotations to generate the correct JAX-WS xml structure.

Actually, the generated XML request structure for WSDL is this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:test="http:..ommited..">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:makePayment>
         <makePayment>   <----- this is the problem, i want to remove it
            <value></value>
            <date></date>
         </makePayment>
      </test:makePayment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And its response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <test:makePaymentResponse xmlns:test="http://.../">
         <makePayment>    <----- this is the problem, i want to remove it
            <status></status>
         </makePayment>
      </test:makePaymentResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

i want to remove the inner makePayment tag and let the request/response be like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <test:makePayment>
        <value></value>
        <date></date>
    </test:makePayment>
</soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Body>
    <test:makePaymentResponse>
        <status></status>
    </test:makePayment>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I understand that it could be possible to simply remove VO from method parameter and change to each parameter separately, but i would like to keep the VO there and change something in my XML annotations, but i can't find what exactly.

My JAVA interface:

```
@WebService
public interface IPag {
        @WebResult(name="makePayment")
        @WebMethod(operationName="makePayment")
        public MakePaymentResponseVO makePayment(MakePaymentRequestVO vo);
}
```

My RequestVO:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"value","date"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "makePaymentRequest")
public class MakePaymentRequestVO {
    @XmlElement(name = "value", required = true)
    private String value;
    @XmlElement(name = "date", required = true)
    private String date;
    ...get/set...
}
```

My ResponseVO:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"status"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "makePaymentResponse")
public class MakePaymentResponseVO {
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private String status;
    ...get/set...
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

At,
AA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the name of MakePaymentResponseVO into @WebResult ? :

The JAVA interface:

```
@WebService
public interface IPag {
        @WebResult(name="makePaymentResponse", targetNamespace="http://.../")
        @WebMethod(operationName="makePayment")
        public MakePaymentResponseVO makePayment(MakePaymentRequestVO r);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed like you said. but this was the new xml response:

    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<S:Body>
<test:makePaymentResponse xmlns:test="http://.../">
>                <makePaymentResponse> <--- i still want to remove it
>                <status></status>
>             </makePaymentResponse>
>          </test:makePaymentResponse>
>      </S:Body>
></S:Envelope>